# Can I assign a function path or deeper value to a constant within a class?

Tags: php, class, constants

I read somewhere at some point that this can't be done, but I'm wondering if there is just another way to go about it.

Right now I have the following...

`define('CUSTOM_THEME_BACKEND_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory())`;

But I would like it to be within a class like the following...

```
const CUSTOM_THEME_BACKEND_PATH = get_stylesheet_directory();
```

Then I can run something like the following...

```
MyConstantClass::CUSTOM_THEME_BACKEND_PATH . '/path/to/file'
```

Is there anyway I can assign more complicated values to a constant within a class?

*Reference:* http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

I would like to protect my constant by the class, but also I am creating a theme that has quite a bit of options and I have to define those values quite a bit. I would like to cut down on that, which would also let me change things in the future with less work.

I would like to assign something like the above and also the following...

```
const Option = get_options_data('custom-theme-custom-assets', 'enable-custom-skins');
```

Then if I can do something like the following...

```
if (isset(MyConstantClass::Option) && MyConstantClass::Option == 'true'){}
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Your first step to figuring this out is deciding if you're writing your code in C++ or PHP. You have to pick one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's in php. I'm not sure about all the coding languages and what C++ really was. But I chose that tag "only" because SO recommended it as a tag after I created everything and already chosen my tags. Otherwise I wouldn't have chosen it. I was putting my trust in the SO. But, noted, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "mutable" keyword to have some of the class's fields changeable, and set them in the following lines.

However, this is highly irregular and should be considered carefully.

Comment: This is in php, not C++, so based from my search and that I wrongly tagged this as php, I don't think the mutable keyword is available outside of C++? My searches only returned mutable keyword articles for C++. However, if this is highly irregular I would rather avoid it as I'm still new to php, especially classes in php. This has just been on my mind so I was hoping there just might already be a more normal alternative that I just didn't know about (being new to classes).